# A Calculus please help

Tags: calculus-of-variations

This is kinda a typical question of. But I'm really stuck in this.

Is there any one how to solve thisquestion.
Really really appreciate it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58739/discussion-on-question-by-pengyang-wu-a-calculus-of-variation-question-please-h).

Comment: Hi @arjafi, I believe the conversation contains lots of meaningful and useful info. Would you mind put some selected comments back so other **beginners** could benefit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The optimal $y$ in the functional
$$\int_a^b L(y,y',x)\, dx$$
must satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} = 0$$
Here, we have $L(y,y',x) = (y')^2+12xy$. Plugging this into the ELE gives us
$$12x - \frac{d}{dx}(2y') = 12x - 2y'' = 0$$
i.e.
$$y'' = 6x$$
and so
$$y = x^3+c_1 x+c_2$$
for some constants $c_1, c_2$ which you can solve for using $y(0) = 0, y(1)=1$.